# React native axios or fetch after running down line problem, used async function but not working code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
const onSearchValue = async() => {
  console.log('searching');
  axiosConfig
    .post(
      '/search' +
      '?WebUsr=' +
      myWebUsr
    )
    .then(async(res) => {

      const json = res.data;
      console.log(json);
      setSearchResult(json); ** //but it's 2nd worked**
    })
    .catch(async(err) => {
      console.log('Catch error=' + err);
    });

  if (searchResult.Val == '-1') {
    setVisible(true);
    setMsg('Not Found');
    return;
  }
  console.log('header-1'); //**//1st worked**
}
```

Comment: You need to add more details, the title is not enough information. Where do you think the problem is? What have you tried? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Axios make an API call by post method to the server and server will return response which may take time.

So until server not return response. execution on client computer can't wait.
So execution control jumps post request and then execute next line of program. So If you want to process `API result` then you should keep your further code in `.then` Method like this :

```
 const onSearchValue = async () => { 
    console.log('searching'); 
      axiosConfig.post( '/search' + '?WebUsr=' + myWebUsr ).then(async (res) => {
        const json = res.data;
        console.log(json);
        setSearchResult(json); **//but it's 2nd worked**

        if (searchResult.Val== '-1') {
          setVisible(true);
          setMsg('Not Found');
          return;
        }

      }).catch(async (err) => {
        console.log('Catch error=' + err);
      });
    
    console.log('header-1'); //**//1st worked**
    }
```

Or you also should try this code :

```
await axiosConfig.post( '/search' + '?WebUsr=' + myWebUsr ).then(async (res) => {
```